# 'Import-Module' not able to load cmdlet dll

Tags: powershell, tfs, msbuild, powershell-cmdlet

I have created a custom cmdlet to get the TFS Version control Server object (`Get-VersionControlServer`) in `C#`. I want to use this cmdlet in my TFS 2017 MSBuild build Definition, in the `MsBuild.ps1` file but, when  I use the `Import-Module` command to import my dll and run the build it is giving me an error saying:

> The 'Get-VersionControlServer'  was not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, a function, a script file, or an executable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if the path is correct (Immediately included), and repeat the process.

Also, when I try to import the cmdlet and run in the PowerShell ISE console, it works fine, but not from the `MSBuild.ps1` file.

I already searched for the solution and went through lot of comments on the similar issue, but it did not work for me.  Has anyone faced a similar problem or can help me with this issue?

Comment: I'd suggest you look at your Module path.. $env:PSModulePath also do a Get-command  Get-VersionControlServer to see what module that command is in.

Comment: Does your module have a manifest?

Comment: What's the result if you try to use this through visual studio MSbuild instead of TFS build definition? It's also use the same  thing as local MSbuild. This will narrow down if the issue related to TFS build definition.

Comment: @thomschumacher: when I do  $env:PSModulePath , it returns the path where my module is placed. Get-command Get-VersionControlServer lists the module and my cmdlet so, I guess there is no Problem in that.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1: Yes, my module has a manifile file. When I try to import using the manifest same Problem persists.

Comment: @PatrickLu-MSFT: I tried with visual Studio MSbuild but still it is throwing the same error.